# Attaching .mov to MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, email-attachments, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to send .mov file via email. So I am using MFMailComposeViewController. After spending some time for searching I finally wrote below code.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Saved Video/%@",[player.contentURL lastPathComponent]]];
MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mail addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myPathDocs]] mimeType:@"video/quicktime" fileName:[myPathDocs lastPathComponent]];
[mail setSubject:@"Share VIDEO by My App"];
[self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When Mail composer appears I can see attachment in the mail body but I receive this mail without attachment.
Am I missing something? or Doing something wrong?

Please help me.

Comment: What's the size of the video?

Comment: not calculated, but video is of 480p of 3 second. So not more then 4-5 MB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't getting the data for the file correctly.

The first step is to split up your code so it's more readable and far easier to debug. Split this line:

```
[mail addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myPathDocs]] mimeType:@"video/quicktime" fileName:[myPathDocs lastPathComponent]];
```

into these:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myPathDocs];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
[mail addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"video/quicktime" fileName:[myPathDocs lastPathComponent]];
```

Now when you debug this code you will find that `fileData` is `nil`. `fileURL` will also be `nil` (or at least an invalid URL).

Change this line:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myPathDocs];
```

to:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];
```

You need to do this since `myPathDocs` is a file path, not a URL string.

Also, you should fix how you build `myPathDocs`. Instead of:

```
NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Saved Video/%@",[player.contentURL lastPathComponent]]];
```

You should do something like:

```
NSString *myPathDocs = [[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Saved Video"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[player.contentURL lastPathComponent]];
```

Comment: Thnx, buddy. I don't know why I was creating URL with string instead of fileURL. May be I created mistake in hurry!!!